# Trigger jQuery mousemove event only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I'm trying to make an exit popup and I could do that using the following code.
Whenever the user's mouse move out of the browser area, this gives a popup. But it is quite annoying when the popup comes everytime. I want to limit it to just a single time.
Can somebody help me with this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        jQuery('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth/2 - jQuery('#exitpopup').width()/2));
        jQuery('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight/2 - jQuery('#exitpopup').height()/2));
        if(e.pageY <= 5)
        {
            // Show the exit popup
            jQuery('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
            jQuery('#exitpopup').fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Set a flag which indicates whether the popup has been shown before or not. Or unbind the event handler after the popup was shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's `one()` function: http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(document).one('mousemove', function(e) {
            jQuery('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth/2 - jQuery('#exitpopup').width()/2));
            jQuery('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight/2 - jQuery('#exitpopup').height()/2));
            if(e.pageY <= 5)
            {   
                // Show the exit popup
                jQuery('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
                jQuery('#exitpopup').fadeIn();
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Cullen, this works. Though Ben's answer did the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

just at the first list of the mousemouve function.

```
....
jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
    jQuery('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth/2 - jQuery('#exitpopup').width()/2));
    ...
```

Comment: And to where do the document propogate, other than maybe the window ?

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var leftPage = false;
        $(document).mousemove(function(e) {

            if(e.pageY <= 5)
            {
                if (!leftPage) {
                    var exitPopup = $('#exitpopup');
                    exitPopup.css('left', (window.innerWidth/2 - exitPopup.width()/2));
                    exitPopup.css('top', (window.innerHeight/2 - exitPopup.height()/2));
                    $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
                    exitPopup.fadeIn();
                }

                leftPage = true;
            } else {
                leftPage = false;
            }
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

"If the user leaves the page AND they have not already left THEN set popup. Next mark that they have left the page (leftPage = true)"

"Do not try and set the popup again until they are back in the page"

Couple of extras:

- Instead of calling `jQuery` all the time we wrap the whole thing in a function wrapper so you can use `$`.
- Instead of doing this everytime `$('#exitpopup');` we CACHE it to a variable `exitPopup` so it doesn't have to do the lookup every time (inefficient)

Comment: My bad, It doesn't help. Also I have a bit more of code to close the popup.
`jQuery('#exitpopup_bg').click(function(){
            jQuery('#exitpopup_bg').fadeOut();
            jQuery('#exitpopup').slideUp();`

Comment: Not really sure what you are after then, I thought you wanted to show the popup at the right time and only once regardless of what your popup code is. If you check here and move the cursor in the right window you can see the console log appearing at the right time and only once http://jsfiddle.net/3sSvU/

Comment: The code I mentioned above is just to close/hide the popup which appeared, something like a close button. Clicking on it will trigger to hide the popup which appeared. Hope you got my point.

And regarding the console log, refer the following screenshot. It is being logged more than once. http://screencast.com/t/g8uzYvEKa

Answer (score 0):

A few things here. First, for form's sake, you should move your CSS alterations inside the `if` block, because you really don't need those to run every time the user moves their mouse, just right before you show the popup:

```
if(e.pageY <= 5)
{   
    // Alter CSS as appropriate
    jQuery('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth/2 - jQuery('#exitpopup').width()/2));
    jQuery('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight/2 - jQuery('#exitpopup').height()/2));

    // Show the exit popup
    jQuery('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
    jQuery('#exitpopup').fadeIn();
}
```

Second, you'll probably want to avoid showing it a second time by detaching the event handler. I'd recommend you use the jQuery `.on()` and `.off()` syntax instead of the shorthand `.mousemove()` because it'll be easier to read and maintain. I also recommend you use namespaces on your events so you can ensure that you're not detaching events that might have been set in other scripts.

```
jQuery(document).on('mousemove.yourNamespace', function (e) {
    if(e.pageY <= 5)
    {   
        // Alter CSS as appropriate
        jQuery('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth/2 - jQuery('#exitpopup').width()/2));
        jQuery('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight/2 - jQuery('#exitpopup').height()/2));

        // Show the exit popup
        jQuery('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
        jQuery('#exitpopup').fadeIn();

        // now detach the event handler so it won't fire again
        jQuery(document).off('mousemove.yourNamespace');
    }
}
```

Lastly, if you wrap all of this code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), you won't have to write out `jQuery` every time, and you still won't have to worry about possible conflicts with `$` in the global namespace.

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).on('mousemove.yourNamespace', function (e) {
        if(e.pageY <= 5)
        {   
            // Alter CSS as appropriate
            $('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth/2 - $('#exitpopup').width()/2));
            $('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight/2 - $('#exitpopup').height()/2));

            // Show the exit popup
            $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
            $('#exitpopup').fadeIn();

            // now detach the event handler so it won't fire again
            $(document).off('mousemove.yourNamespace');
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

jQuery docs for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/), and [event.namespace](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Ben. I'll surely consider them. My bad that the code doesn't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work?" If it's that the popup isn't displaying properly, it might be the condition in your `if` statement. `e.pageY <= 5` is just going to tell you when the mouse is within the first 5 pixels of the top of the page. You'll need a more complex condition if you want to detect any time the user leaves the page.

Comment: Sorry Ben, it was something from my side while copying your code that resulted in the issue. It works now!

Comment: Glad to hear it. One thing you might want to look into is the `mouseleave` event. You should be able to set `$(window).on('mouseleave', ...)` which will fire when the mouse leaves the window, so you don't have to mess with e.pageX and e.pageY. Just turn it off with the same `.off()` notation described above.

Comment: Yeah, I'll surely consider that!